# Do I need to pay income tax to use the money of my own company?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Suppose I own a company. I am the only member of the company. I pay corporate taxes on the bills that my company emits to the customers. That's done.

If I want to use the money of the company for whatever thing unrelated to the company, do I need to also pay income taxes on it?

Comment: What kind of company is it? Is it a partnership? A C corp? An S corp?

Comment: The "unrelated thing" would probably be considered income to you.  Say you have your company buy a private jet, which you then use for personal, non-business travel.  The IRS would consider that income: https://www.conklindd.com/t-personaluseofcorporateaircraft.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, a single-member corporation is considered by the IRS as a pass-through entity. That means that the company income passes directly to you as your personal income. You pay personal income tax on whatever income the company generates for you.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. Also wondering about other countries.

Comment: @Jose There are about 190 countries — are you looking for an answer for each of them?

Comment: If the situation is different then yes. My guess is in many countries might be quite equivalent. That's what I want to figure out.

Comment: ... and if the OP had a C-corp, your advice would have just got him into serious trouble with the IRS. How can you answer this question, without knowing the type of corporation the OP is actually running?